# What does "take comfort in your friends" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

What does "take comfort in your friends" mean?

I've stumbled upon this phrase in the "Rem - Everybody Hurts" song.

> [...]Everybody hurts
>
> Take comfort in your friends [...]

And I haven't found the appropriate phrase in the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Comfort" can mean solace, the easing of grief, pain, and distress.  The admonition means that when you're hurting, turn to your friends for help in easing your distress.

Comment: It's very similar in meaning to "take comfort from."  One difference may be that native speakers are more likely to use "take comfort in" rather than "from" when a person or group of people is the indirect object, because it doesn't sound nice to take (away) things from people.  But we frequently say "take comfort from the fact that . . . ." -- though "in" works there, as well.